# Using Laravel ACL Package with Laravel 4.2

Tags: laravel-4, acl

I'm trying to install this Laravel ACL package: https://github.com/Vivify-Ideas/laravel-acl#installation. When I update composer to install the package, I get the following error:

> our requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of
>   packages.
>
> Problem 1
>       - Installation request for vivify-ideas/acl dev-master -> satisfiable by vivify-ideas/acl[dev-master].
>       - Conclusion: remove laravel/framework 4.2.x-dev
>       - vivify-ideas/acl dev-master requires illuminate/support 4.0.x -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[4.0.x-dev],
>   illuminate/support[4.0.x-dev, v4.0.0, v4.0.0-BETA2, v4.0.0-BETA3,
>   v4.0.0-BETA4, v4.0.1, v4.0.10, v4.0.2, v4.0.3, v4.0.4, v4.0.5, v4.0.6,
>   v4.0.7, v4.0.8, v4.0.9].
>       - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[4.2.x-dev, 4.0.x-dev].

Comment: What do you mean run composer.json? the file you should run in command line is composer.phar or just composer if it's in your path.

Comment: I mean when I update my composer to install the package, I get that error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly... that ACL was designed for Laravel 4.
Laravel 4.2 actually has RBAC built into it so you don't need to use that.

There are multiple changes between versions 4, 4.1 and 4.2.  So even if you did install it with composer it wouldn't work.

Secondly... Laravel 4.2 is still in development so I wouldn't use it yet.
Composer is reporting that you need to replace laravel 4.2.* with 4.0.*.

You could update the composer file for it to require laravel: 4.2.* but I'd advise against it (you'd just be coming back here as it will provide more issues)

---Edit---
Ignore the bit about RBAC being built into 4.2... I read that in January from one of the framework developers... alas I haven't found it after going through it.
However there's plenty of guides for rbac and acl.  Just don't copy and paste.

Answer (score 1):

There is a full built-in package and admin panel based on sentry here: https://github.com/intrip/laravel-authentication-acl